# Stored procedures and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, stored-procedures

Is it worth coding in stored procedures or in the code (or separate class).

I read somewhere that stored procedures are faster in their execution, because they sit on the database, and it doesn't need to make the interpretation stage when it reads php code.

I like coding in a separate file the mysql code that I need and refer it from there. Would it make a difference if I used stored procedures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came upon this problem.

Using stored procedures on the DB is much faster, when you create the SP it compiles it down into an intermediate code that it can run faster than having to parse standard SQL statements at run time. ALSO the biggest advantage of SP's is that you can pass in some params, and you can make the SP do a whole load of work on the DB, which can be controlled using IF ELSE statements and CASES, this also keeps traffic between your application and the DB to a minimum.

One final advantage to SP's, you can keep the DB implementation seperate from your application implementation, this mean that if say you do an insert in 10 different places in your application, then you change the way the insert needs to be done, you need to go back and change that insert in those 10 different places, whereas if you used an SP to wrap up the insert you can then just change that SP on the fly and the application doesnt need to know ;)

If your already scripting out your SQL code, then your practically 75% home on writing SP's

EDIT: If you use the PHP MySQLi, you may or may not be aware that calling stored procedures returns 2 rowsets as opposed to standard queries that only return 1, but this isn't too bigger problem as long as you know its coming :-)

Comment: A properly written PHP application is going to have a separate DB abstraction layer anyway.  So a change in insert syntax *should* still have a single revision point.  That being said, you are still correct that SPs execute faster so they are still a good idea based on performance alone.

Answer (score 2):

If you use stored procedures, the code to generate them will exist similarly to how you store your `CREATE TABLE` statements. It will likely have no interaction with your PHP code.  Stored procedures are stored in MySQL the same way that tables and views are - you rarely create them at runtime with code.

So just create a file called something like `procedures.sql` to code your stored procedures and load them into the database just as you would do with your `CREATE TABLE` statements.  After executing the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statements from their SQL file, it can be removed from your web server. It should not reside anywhere in web-accessible space.

Both stored procedures and prepared statements offer performance and security gains.  The benefit of stored procedures over prepared statements is that your database logic can become decoupled from your application code.  That allows you to perform the same database actions from different application interfaces, if it is ever necessary to do so.

Comment: But are there performance and security gains from using stored procedures

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd Yes there are. I am not advocating against using them, just explaining how they are used.

Comment: Have you got any source of information where I can read on how to use them with mysql..phpmyadmin?

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd See addition about differences of using SP over prepared statements.

Comment: @DmitryMakovetskiyd I don't know of any specific reference. SP's are often executed as prepared statements with PDO or MySQLi.  `$db->prepare("CALL stored_procedure_name(?,?,?)");

Answer (score 1):

See:  http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/news/1052737/Why-use-stored-procedures.

Basically, it is better if you keep database logic in the database and not muddy your php code with sql, which can be hard to maintain.  Also, since stored procedures are compiled, they perform better.